# Joomla: Need to create new page with form filled by user details

Tags: joomla

I am new to Joomla and it is difficult to understand API for me.

I want to create simple page with form fields, which will have current logged in user details. That will be submitted to 3rd party site for payment processing.

Any one help me, what is way for creating dynamic page?

Answer (score 0):

You can work like this,

If this form needs to display only for logged users then

Create new layout under `components/com_users/view/profile/tmpl/new_layout.php`

Also you can set the values required for this page through `components/com_users/view/profile/view.html.php` by checking layout and call a function that return necessary data from its model

here it profile.php under `components/com_users/models/`

In your custom form new_layout.php you can add form action like 
`index.php?option=com_users&view=profile&task=profile.addNewData`;

This will send the form data to profile.php controller the function name addNewData()

You can call profile model from this controller.

I think you will get little bit idea about what you have to done .

Comment: thanks @Jobin Jose. i created simple mod from sample hello world mod.

Comment: but you ask for new layout creation right ? not for module ? any way good luck for achieve your goal.